# Local defines in R5RS Scheme language in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

When I write the following code with two local defines in DrRacket using the `#lang r5rs` language standard I get an error:

```
(define (f)
   (define a -8)
   ;a
   (define b a)
   (display b))

(f)
```

It says that the `a` inside the `(define b a)` is undefined, despite the fact that it was just defined the line above.

```
a: undefined;
cannot use before initialization
```

If we uncomment the line `;a` however and thus force the evaluation of `a` just before the `(define b a)` the code works and prints `-8` as expected. Why doesn't it work in the first case? Is this specific to how *defines* are implemented in DrRacket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [according to R5RS standard section 5.2.2 "Internal definitions)](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.2) a sequence of `define` that occur at the beginning of the `<body>` can be replaced with `letrec` and the code with commented out `a` is equivalent to

```
#lang r5rs
(define (f)
  (letrec ((a -8)
           (b a))
   (display b)))

(f)
```

while the code with uncommented `a` is equivalent to

```lisp
#lang r5rs
(define (f)
  (letrec ((a -8))
    a
    (define b a)
    (display b)))

(f)
```

Here `(define b a)` occurs neither at the top level nor at the beginning of the `<body>` so the behavior is not defined by the standard, but Racket allows this.

Note that it also works if you insert any other expression after the first define, for example:

```lisp
#lang r5rs
(define (f)
   (define a -8)
   #t
   (define b a)
   (display b))

(f)
```

Comment: _"Note that it also works if you insert any other expression after the first define"_ -- this is quite unclear: what works?

Comment: OK thanks this would explain that behaviour.